# how to solve linear equations involving modulo?

Tags: linear-algebra

In one of my projects, I encountered a set of linear eqns. with modulo.  I am putting it in simple format with only 2 variables,

(a11x + a12y) mod 8 = b1
(a21x + a22y) mod 8  = b2

In case of simple eqns. with out modulo I can use: AX=B, X=inv(A)*B.  But how to handle this modulo?  Any clue or pointers will be very helpful.

Comment: Try new math stackexchange. http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: sorry, I didn't know about this.  o.k. moving this question there.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved successfully? Do you still need help with this? Should this question be closed?

Comment: I was struggling on that part with out a solution but due to other project work, temporarily put that on hold.  Here I would like to close this question since it is already moved to math.stackexchange.com.  Thanks for the follow up.

Comment: Question on Mathematics SE; https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9370/how-to-solve-linear-equations-involving-modulo

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a math question already reasked on Mathematics SE; http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9370/how-to-solve-linear-equations-involving-modulo